# Errors were encountered while processing:

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu

I made a mess out of my self. 
I wanted to add python3.6 in my system so I decided to uninstall the existing one in my Ubuntu 19.10 . But now everytime I want to install something I get error like this:

> dpkg: error while cleaning up:
>    installed python3-virtualenv package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit 
>    status 127
>
> Errors were encountered while processing:python3-virtualenv
>
> Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
>   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I can't open my terminal by clicking on icon and I can't even install any apps from ubuntu sofware.Any suggestion to follow

**System**
Ubunutu 19.10

Comment: Can you open your terminal on other ways?

Comment: Try to reboot your system, these things happen

Comment: Also, how did you uninstall Python?

Comment: I can if I right click inside mnt and click open terminal

Comment: @Bonfire sudo rm /usr/bin/python3 .7.

Comment: Try reinstalling Python with `sudo apt install python3.7` or `python3` for the newest version.

Comment: This is a common thing people tend to do without understanding why they shouldn't. In the future, don't uninstall the system version of Python unless you know precisely what you're doing. Here is an answer from the Ubuntu stackexchange: https://askubuntu.com/questions/384033/removed-python-3-and-now-ubuntu-software-center-terminal-and-other-applications

Comment: @JosephGlover I cant install anything I get the same error mentioned in the question

Comment: @manish, yes, see the answers already given in those posts.

Comment: @Justlearnedit Can't install anything got the same error

Comment: So I guess that you cannot use wget either...

Comment: @Bonfire I have not tried yet.. If you got any help please help me

Comment: Is the WiFi working properly or not?

Comment: Wifi is working fine ..

Comment: If you have wget and make installed, you will be able to install Python 3.8.0. However, I don't think that doing so will fix everything else.

Comment: This guide is for Raspbian, but it does work for Ubuntu as well. If you have the dependencies installed, you will be able to download Python.

Comment: If not, then I guess that you may have to reinstall Ubuntu in your system... There could be alternatives that I am not aware of, though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211123/discussion-between-manish-and-bonfire).

Comment: If you see any answer related this question anywhere please contact me

Answer (score 2):

I have found the answer. Just wrote the line in the terminal

```bash
sudo apt install python3-minimal python3 --reinstall
```